# g++: create a shared library (.so) with static glibc?

Tags: linux, g++, glibc, static-linking, shared-objects

I'm trying to create a shared library (.so file) that will include its own copy of glibc and link to it statically.
I am already linking to libgcc and libstdc++ statically using `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` in addition to `-shared -fPIC` and it works great.

What combination of flags do I need to set to link to the static version of glibc as well?

I tried adding `-static` to the lot but got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/crtbeginT.o: 
  relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__DTOR_END__' can not be used when making a 
  shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/.../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/crtbeginT.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

Comment: Don't do that. You'll get a lot of trouble. Instead, consider patching your Glibc (or your variant of [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) which might be easier to patch).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can you be more specific?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I am sure there are simpler means to achieve your overall goal (which you did not tell).